# Calculate file path with field calculator

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table

Does anyone have script out there to calculate the file path name with the field calculator....I am trying to add a field with the file path name so I can keep track of the original source directory of .shp's.

Comment: What software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [describe() from arcpy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000026000000).  One of the [describe object's properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Describe_object_properties/000v0000002n000000/) includes a path to whatever object you passed to it.  So you could use a loop to iterate through all your shapefiles, then add a field, and set the value of the field to be equal to the path property.

Answer (score 1):

Understandable need, but use standard metadata for your data not a field in the database. ArcGIS will track many events like geoprocessing run on the data automatically. Check it out in ArcCatalog and online help here http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_automatic_metadata_updates/003t0000000q000000/